# How to get/count the total sold products and its sales

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first time to use ruby on rails. I just want to know on how to get the product if I multiply the product_cost and quantity_sold even every time I add/input another sold product/Item. And  also how to count its over all total sales. This is where I want to put the code. I would really appreciate your answers and suggestions. Thank you!

Inside the index.

views\solds\index

```
<p I'd="notice"><℅= notice ℅><p>

<h1><List of Sold Product></h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Category</th>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>Product code</th>
      <th>Product desc</th>
      <th>Product cost</th>
      <th>Quantity sold</th>
      <th>Date sold</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  <thead>


  <tbody>
    <℅ @solds.each do |sold| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= sold.product_category %></td>
      <td><%= sold.product_name %></td>
      <td><%= sold.product_code %></td>
      <td><%= sold.product_desc %></td>
      <td><%= sold.product_cost %</td>
      <td><%= sold.quantity_sold %></td>
      <td><%= sold.date_sold %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', sold %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit',edit_sold_path(sold) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sold,   method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>.                
    </tr> 
   <℅ end ℅>
  </tbody>
</table>


<br>
<%= link_to 'New Sold', new_sold_path %>
```

Comment: you need a column or below table where you can show total of product_cost for solds ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with:

```
Total Cost : <%= @solds.sum(:product_cost) %>
Total Quantity : <%= @solds.sum(:quantity_sold) %>
```

Add This code below of the table listing

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this below table

```
Total Cost : <%= @solds.reduce(0){|s, sum| sum + s.product_cost} %>
Total Quantity : <%= @solds.reduce(0){|s, sum| sum + s.quantity_sold} %>
```